# Tile server - problem with tiles loading (pink tiles)

Tags: openstreetmap, ubuntu, rendering

I have built a tile server by following this instruction: https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/building-a-tile-server-from-packages/ and i have a problem.
When i test tile server using http://localhost/osm/slippymap.html, some tiles are pink. After zoom out and zoom in tiles are usually properly displayed. 
I tried to run renderd in debugging mode. This is the sample output:

```
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Got command RenderPrio fd(12) xml(default), z(11), x(1156), y(691), mime(image/png), options()
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 13, number 6
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Got command RenderPrio fd(13) xml(default), z(11), x(1158), y(691), mime(image/png), options()
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: DONE TILE default 11 1160-1167 688-695 in 6.073 seconds
debug: Creating and writing a metatile to /var/lib/mod_tile/default/11/0/0/66/139/128.meta

renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Sending render cmd(3 default 11/1160/689) with protocol version 2 to fd 8
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Sending render cmd(3 default 11/1160/690) with protocol version 2 to fd 10
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Sending render cmd(3 default 11/1160/688) with protocol version 2 to fd 9
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Failed to read cmd on fd 8
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Connection 0, fd 8 closed, now 5 left
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Failed to read cmd on fd 10
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Connection 1, fd 10 closed, now 4 left
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Failed to read cmd on fd 9
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Connection 0, fd 9 closed, now 3 left
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 8, number 4
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Got command RenderPrio fd(8) xml(default), z(11), x(1155), y(691), mime(image/png), options()
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 9, number 5
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Got command RenderPrio fd(9) xml(default), z(11), x(1159), y(691), mime(image/png), options()
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 10, number 6
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Got command RenderPrio fd(10) xml(default), z(11), x(1154), y(691), mime(image/png), options()
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Failed to read cmd on fd 11
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Connection 0, fd 11 closed, now 5 left
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Failed to read cmd on fd 12
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Connection 0, fd 12 closed, now 4 left
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Failed to read cmd on fd 13
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Connection 0, fd 13 closed, now 3 left
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Failed to read cmd on fd 8
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Connection 0, fd 8 closed, now 2 left
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Failed to read cmd on fd 9
renderd[19572]: DEBUG: Connection 0, fd 9 closed, now 1 left
```

I've also tried to pre-render tiles for region. Command for pre-rendering is for example:

```
render_list -all -s /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock -x 34 -X 36 -y 20 -Y 21 -z 6 -Z 6
```

Pre-rendering process displays messages pasted below and i don't know if it is working still or not:

```
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/lib/mod_tile
Rendering client
Starting 1 rendering threads
Rendering all tiles from zoom 6 to zoom 6
Rendering all tiles for zoom 6 from (34, 20) to (36, 21)
Waiting for rendering threads to finish
```

I can't see new tiles in /var/lib/mod_tile after that process.

Why does it happen (pink tiles)? How can I prevent this?

Comment: Is your rendering server poor performance (e.g. a VM? or a laptop with slow disk/?)

Comment: It's a virtual server residing on physical server.

Comment: That doesn't really say much. What sort of virtualisation? What virtual characteristics? How much load is the host on?

Comment: Virtualisation is made using VMWare. Server has 2 virtual CPUs. Turning RAM up (from 4GB to 8GB and to 16 GB) doesn't take effect. 
Data covers country extract (not whole planet). Disk usage is about 50%. Physical server is not loaded too much.
The 'top' command sometimes shows (during map repainting) that CPU "wa" value grow from 0% to about 50%. Pink tiles usually appear after that. I don't know if it is any clue.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. It was a silly mistake with render_list (literal error)... It should be "--all" or "-a", not "-all". This option was not recognized (with no error message). The command was waiting for x y and z parameters from stdin. 
Using render_list in proper way solved my problem. Pink tiles don't appear after that.